# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning

Tags: node.js

В ноде возникает ошибка:

```
(node:40408) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: null
(node:40408) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)
```

А как узнать где именно в коде это происходит?

Еще пишет

```
(node:39468) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Что Unhandled promise rejections  устарели и их заменит завершение процесса с ошибкой. 
А это уже можно как то включить по умолчанию?

Comment: Для начала попробовать решение отсюда https://stackoverflow.com/a/43994999/1016033